# Uploading and requesting images from Meteor app

Tags: node.js, http, meteor, iron-router

I want to upload images from the client to the server. The client must see a list of all images he or she has and see the image itself (a thumbnail or something like that).

I saw people using two methods (generically speaking)

1- Upload image and save the binaries to MongoDB

2- Upload an image and move it to a folder, save the path somewhere (the classic method, and the one I implemented so far)

What are the pros and cons of each method and how can I retrieve the data and show it in a template in each case (getting the path and writing to the `src` attribute of and `img` tag and sending the binaries) ?

Problems found so far: when I request `foo.jpg` (localhost:3000/uploads/foo.jpg) that I uploaded and the server moved to a known folder, my router (iron router) fails to find how to deal with the request.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Upload image and save the binaries to MongoDB

Either you limit the file size to 16MB and use only basic mongoDB, either you use gridFS and can store anything (no size limit). There are several pro-cons of using this method, but IMHO it is much better than storing on the file system :

- Files don't touch your file system, they are piped to you database
- You get back all the benefits of mongo and you can scale up without worries
- Files are chunked and you can only send a specific byte range (useful for streaming or download resuming)
- Files are accessed like any other mongo document, so you can use the allow/deny function, pub/sub, etc.

> 2- Upload an image and move it to a folder, save the path somewhere
>   (the classic method, and the one I implemented so far)

In this case, either you store everything in your public folder and make everything publicly accessible using the files names + paths, either you use dedicated asset delivery system, such as an ngix server. Either way, you will be using something less secure and maintenable than the first option.

This being said, have a look at [the file collection package](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection). It is much simpler than collection-fs and will offer you everything you are looking for out of the box (including a file api, gridFS storing, resumable uploads, and many other things).

---

> Problems found so far: when I request foo.jpg
>   (localhost:3000/uploads/foo.jpg) that I uploaded and the server moved
>   to a known folder, my router (iron router) fails to find how to deal
>   with the request.

Do you know this path leads to your root folder `public/uploads/foo.jpg` directory? If you put it there, you should be able to request it.